# How can I add React to my Visual Studio project (web appliction)?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, visual-studio

I want to add React to my project, how can I use React for my project in VS?

I've tried to use links from unkpg, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>React CDN</title>
   <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
   <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
   <script src='https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="root"></div>
   <script type="text/babel">
   const ReactAppFromCDN = ()=>{
   return (
       <div>My React App with CDN</div>
   )
}
  
ReactDOM.render(<ReactAppFromCDN />, document.querySelector('#root'));
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```